# Range Function in Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, range

[example from this dog chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yexa.jpg)

My goal is:

```
def DogYears():
    small_dog = {
    1 : 15,
    2 : 24,
    3 : 28,
    4 : 32,
    5 : 36
    6 : 40
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

My question is how could I automate this process so that I don't have to fill it manually?

I was thinking of something like this, at least in that direction, of course it doesn't work:

```
def DogYears():
    small_dog = {
    range(15, 80, 4)
    }
```

I somehow also need to assign key & value pair. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually need a dictionary? You could just do `def dog_years(age): return age * 7 + 8` or whatever the equation is.

Comment: Are you sure you're wanting to use a dictionary? It seems like you are just storing an ordered index as the key (1,2,3...) which is better represented by storing your dog years as a list since you can access elements by their index with lists. Or as the other commenter mentioned, if it is the same equation each time it is better to have a function compute that.

Comment: If you have an equation, you don't need a dictionary. If you don't have an equation, how will you automate dictionary generation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a dictionary, a simple `for`is enough.

```
   def DogYears():
      small_dog = {}
      small_dog[1] = 15
      i = 2
      for j in range(24, 80, 4):
        small_dog[i] = j
        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list allows you to have the ages keep a normal order and access the values by their index. Since all your keys only increase by one, then using a list would be a more appropriate data structure. You can just store your `range()` result into a list variable. Then to access the correct year, you can get the age like I did in the `GetAge` function passing in the year and list.

```
def DogYears():
    small_dog = range(15, 80, 4)

def GetAge(year, dog_list):
    index = year - 1
    if index >= 0 and index < len(dog_list):
        return dog_list[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *dictionary constructor* with the ranges that include the human years and dog years, you would have to add in the outlier `15`, which would come at the end, if you need the dictionary properly sorted you could then just sort it as well using `lambda`. Also you need to extend your ranges by 1 unit since they are not inclusive.

```
small_dog = dict(zip(range(2, 17), range(24, 84, 4)))
small_dog[1] = 15
small_dog = dict(sorted(small_dog.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
# {1: 15, 2: 24, 3: 28, 4: 32, 5: 36, 6: 40, 7: 44, 8: 48, 9: 52, 10: 56, 11: 60, 12: 64, 13: 68, 14: 72, 15: 76, 16: 80}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based off of Eduardo's answer, I think I have an equation. You don't need a dictionary:

```
def small_dog_years(age):
    if age <= 1: return 15
    return min(24 + (age - 2) * 4, 80)

print(small_dog_years(1)) # 15
print(small_dog_years(2)) # 24
print(small_dog_years(3)) # 28
print(small_dog_years(4)) # 32
print(small_dog_years(8)) # 48
print(small_dog_years(15)) # 76
```

You could then generate your dictionary (if you still wanted to) with a dict comprehension:

```
small_dog = {i: small_dog_years(i) for i in range(1, 17)}
print(small_dog)
>>> {1: 15, 2: 24, 3: 28, 4: 32, 5: 36, 6: 40, 7: 44, 8: 48, 9: 52, 10: 56, 11: 60, 12: 64, 13: 68, 14: 72, 15: 76, 16: 80}
```